# add line between two 2 lines in php file with sed/awk

Tags: linux, sed

I get a php file which contain :

```
<?php
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://M.Y.I.P',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '9.1.4.2',
  );
```

and I would like to insert a line between the line version and the end :

```
  'theme' => 'mytheme',
```

so it must look like this :

```
<?php
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://M.Y.I.P',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '9.1.4.2',
  'theme' => 'mytheme',
  );
```

I'm currently trying with sed or awk but can't find the right syntax, can you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
awk -vs1="'" '/version/{print $0 ORS "  " s1 "theme" s1"  => " s1 "mytheme" s1",";next} 1'  Input_file
```

simply checking string version into Input_file and then printing the line which you want to insert along with the current line and if this string is not found in any line then simply printing the line of Input_file.

EDIT: To edit Input_file itself as follows.

```
awk -vs1="'" '/version/{print $0 ORS "  " s1 "theme" s1"  => " s1 "mytheme" s1",";next} 1' Input_file > file_tmp && mv file_tmp Input_file
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.
It worked but it doesn't add the quote before and after theme and mytheme :
    'dbtype' => 'mysql',
    'version' => '9.1.4.2',
    theme  => mytheme,

Comment: np, glad that it helped, you could mark it as helpful/correct answer if you are satisfied with it, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge here.

Comment: There is just the quote missing before theme and mytheme and it will be perfect

Comment: It's adding, check my edit where I have posted my solution, do you want to change into the Input_file itself ?

Comment: the verbose option isn't accepted, "invalid -v option". I would like to change into the config.php file itself yes. And I still doesn't have the quote.

Comment: try: -v s1 instead of -vs1 and let me know then. It is working fine for me, not sure which OS you are working on?

Comment: It add the text just as expected but it just print it and I would like to write it in the input file

Comment: please check my edit answer now and let us know then

Comment: Thanks a lot, In used : awk -v s1="'" '/version/{print $0 ORS "  " s1 "theme" s1"  => " s1 "mytheme" s1",";next} 1'  config.php > file_tmp && mv config.php config.php.old && mv file_tmp config.php 
And it worked just perfectly.
Again thank you !

Comment: glad that it helped you. keep posting, keep sharing.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v line="'theme'  => 'mytheme'," '1;/version/{$0="  "line;print}' inputfile
<?php
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://M.Y.I.P',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '9.1.4.2',
  'theme'  => 'mytheme',
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r "/^[[:space:]]*'version'/a  'theme' => 'mytheme'," file
```

Use `-i` for in-place edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v s1="'" '/version/{print $0 ORS "  " s1 "theme" s1"  => " s1 "mytheme" s1",";next} 1'  config.php > file_tmp && mv config.php config.php.old && mv file_tmp config.php
```

Just worked exactly as expected, thank you RavinderSingh13 !